# How to transpose a table in a Google Document?

Tags: google-docs

I have a table in a Google Document. How can I convert rows into columns, i.e. transpose the table?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Copy-paste the table into spreadsheet
2. Copy table from spreadsheet
3. In spreadsheet Edit > Paste special > Paste transposed
4. Copy-paste table back

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works great.

Answer (score 7):

I would use the `transpose` command of Sheets for this.

1. Copy-paste the table into spreadsheet, e.g., into the range A1:E7
2. Elsewhere on that sheet, enter `=transpose(A1:E7)`
3. Copy-paste the output back into the document, which will recognize it as a table.

I tested this with a table similar to yours, containing linebreaks in some cells. The only thing lost in the process was the text alignment: the output of `transpose` command always has the default alignment (right-aligned numbers, left-aligned text). But this is not hard to fix manually.

Comment: This answer should be accepted by now

Comment: the table in the question is however a Google Document, not a sheet

Comment: Yes I also need the answer for *Docs* but OP probably should've been more clear, since Google's poor product organization means *Sheets* is a part of the *Docs* suite of products (*Docs* includes *Docs* and *Sheets*, etc.)...

Comment: @Hack-R the title says "Google Document", the body says "Google Document", the screenshot shows a Google Document, the tag says [google-docs]. That's a lot of hints :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt That's what I was implying, but as you can see the answer from 3 years ago that you're commenting on is for Sheets, so I called out the fact that the people who answered may have been confused by the fact that Docs includes Sheets.