# Transposing Column to Row

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script that will transpose a column from one sheet into a row on another sheet. I have already figured out how to do the copy, but I need to figure out how to change the data from vertical to horizontal on the other sheet. Can anyone help me?

Comment: there's a function called transpose you can use: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87824/how-to-transpose-a-table-in-a-google-document

Comment: can I call that in a script? I am aware of the function but I want to call it as part of the script that copies the data.

Comment: http://igoogledrive.blogspot.com/2013/07/transpose-in-google-apps-scripts.html

Comment: I had tried running that script, it said "TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 2, file "Transpose")" How can I make this work?

Comment: I noticed that error too. Maybe this link will be helpful. It mentions arrays, but maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621470/google-spreadsheet-script-how-to-transpose-rotate-multi-dimensional-array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A column of values is represented in Apps Script as `[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]`. A row is represented as `[['a', 'b', 'c']]`. The following functions transform one to the other:

```
function col2row(column) {
  return [column.map(function(row) {return row[0];})];
} 

function row2col(row) {
  return row[0].map(function(elem) {return [elem];});
}
```

Comment: Note that these don't work for transposing matrices. That requires more advanced functions.

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful for me:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var originSheet = ss.getSheetByName("main");
var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("weeks");
var destinationRowNum = 1;
var destinationColNum = 1;

colToRow(originSheet.getRange("labelsCol").getValues(), destinationSheet, destinationRowNum, destinationColNum);
colToRow(originSheet.getRange("mainCol").getValues(), destinationSheet, destinationRowNum +1, destinationColNum);

function colToRow(values, destinationSheet, destinationRowNum, destinationColNum) {//Inspired by http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/transpose
  // Transpose it & write it out
  destinationSheet.getRange(destinationRowNum, destinationColNum, values[0].length, values.length)
    .setValues(Object.keys(values[0]).map ( function (columnNumber) {
      return values.map( function (row) {
        return row[columnNumber];
      });
    })); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to have one single function which converts row->column and column->row, and also works on 2D matrices (called transposing):

```
function transposeMatrix(array) {
  return array[0].map((col, i) => array.map(row => row[i]));
}
```

This is basically restating @Fahwad Ghafoor's excellent answer from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17428705/380607

Note: There is even a built-in formula called `TRANSPOSE`, which you can use inside the spreadsheet if you only need it there (and not need to access it in your code). Use that formula in a cell like this `=TRANSPOSE(A1:B2)`.